# a call to template-function - is it legal?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, function-object

I have a template function (generic func to find the minimum), which look's like that:

```
template<class T, class Func>
int findmin(const T* a, int n, Func less){
   //...
}
```

and a call:

```
int smallest_matrix(const Matrix*a, int n){
    return findmin(a,n,less_matrices);
}
```

where **less_marices** is:

```
bool less_matrices(const Matrix& m1, const Matrix& m2){
     //...
}
```

Is that right syntax?

Shouldn't I define a function-object with operator () which will do the boolean check that **less_matrices** do, and the call for **findmin** shouldn't it look like:

```
 int smallest_matrix(const Matrix*a, int n){
    minMatrixFunc f;
    return findmin<Matrix, minMatrixFunc>(a,n,f);
}
```

where **minMatrixFunc** is a function-object with the right **operator()**???

Comment: No, you can also pass a function, as you did. Anything "callable" works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that right syntax?

Yes.

> Shouldn't I define a function-object with operator ()

You may, but it's not necessary.

You don't show the definition of `findmin`. But presumably, all you do with `Func less` is use the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) on it: `less( argument_list )`. If so, any callable type will do as long as the overload resolution finds a matching argument list. That includes [pointers to functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions), which is what you had used.